# Numerical range of inverse operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator such that the numerical range is contained in $[a,b]$ with $0<a<b< \infty.$ Does it then follow that the numerical range of $T^{-1}$ is contained in $[\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{a}]$?

Comment: What is the domain of T?  You usually don't talk about self adjoint operators on the reals, but your question implies as much.

Comment: the operator is bounded, so it is defined on the Hilbert space and no I am not only talking about the reals.

Comment: But the range of the inverse is contained in the domain of T.  So the range is in you'll Hilbert space, not in the reals

Comment: It necessarily exists  T^(-1) by the fact T be self-adjoint T without you assume it? What do you mean, please, by numerical range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For a bounded selfadjoint operator, its numerical range is the convex hull of its eigenvalues. So if the numerical range of $T$ is $[a,b]$, this tells you that the max and min of the spectrum of $T$ are $b$ and $a$ respectively, so for $T^{-1}$ they are $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$, and the numerical range of $T^{-1}$ is $[b^{-1},a^{-1}]$